# Should I always listen to my body when it comes to consuming lots of protein?

Tags: diet, protein, bodybuilding

I'm a big believer in listening to my body.  I stay on a strict and healthy diet, but once in a while my body craves fat, so I'll opt for french fries to that it out of my system.

Same when I go to the gym, if I feel a body part feels neglected, I'll do whatever I need to do for that body part to feel fulfilled.

But when it comes to consuming protein sometimes I feel like I'm forcing myself.  Sometimes the protein shake becomes impossible to drink.  Water will go in just fine, but I get repulsed by the protein drink.  Would this be a good sign that my body has all the protein it needs at the moment and I should wait before consuming more?  I'm aiming for the 0.75-0.8 gram per pound of protein.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not every stomach is built for protein powder (if that's what you're using) so I think your body is saying that it has to get used to it and/or it just doesn't like the taste. You might just need to find the brand and/or flavor you do like. I personally like Metabolic Drive protein powder - that doesn't seem to be so rough on my digestion. Muscle Milk tends to have a lot of sugar in it.

Recently though, I just make homemade shakes.

Here's my recipe that I throw in a magic bullet:

- Greek yogurt (it has a lot more protein than other yogurt brands but if you find that is too tart, just use a yogurt you like, vanilla might be a good base, and low-fat helps cut out extra calories)
- Ripe banana
- 2 big tablespoons of peanut butter
- If I want to splurge, I throw a little bit of Nutella in there

You can throw in protein powder if you want or greens. If you are strength training, I think you need to try to meet your protein intake. Do some experimenting or try a home shake. In the meantime, get the rest of your servings from protein you **do** like: eggs, chicken, lean beef, [and what have you](http://www.webmd.com/fitness-exercise/guide/good-protein-sources).

Comment: You like the magic bullet?  I see them in stores here & there and am tempted to get one.

Comment: It's OK - it IS easier to clean than a blender though because it's lighter. I have it because it was a gift. Initially I liked it because of the storage containers but I really don't store any of my drinks. If you do a lot of storing, clean out mason jars from store-bought spaghetti sauce -there are 2 diff. threads on mason jars. You want the bigger thread which is the bigger circumference. Some blenders use that standard thread. I took a mason jar to Macys and installed it in blenders until I found one. It was a Kitchen Aid Food Processor/Blender. Homemade magic bullet with a better motor! :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't necessarilly think that you being replused by the drink is your body rejecting it, rather just the fact that protein drinks are often not very nice. It sounds as though you're probably attempting to get quite a lot of your protein from these drinks. I would advise that you increase the amount of protein in your diet overall in order to hit your 0.8g/lb target. Do this by throwing some more meat into your meals. Fair enough have a shake immediately after training but it's more important to eat properly the rest of the time.

Comment: I'm repulsed by it just like people may get repulsed after eating too much chocolate, I think. But I do like the shakes. It's more like I've had it up to here and no more will go in.  But yeah, I do try to get more protein in other ways.  But consuming 150 grams is hard.

Answer (score 1):

Being repulsed by something doesn't mean that your body doesn't need it. You can be repulsed by fruits and vegetables, but that surely doesn't mean your body doesn't need them.

Diets aren't always fun, however they are necessary if you are trying to obtain a specific body composition or level of health. If you have a plan set out for yourself (in your case approximately 0.8 grams of protein per pound of body weight), stick to it even when it's not enjoyable if you truly want to reach your goals. Sometimes achieving results means doing things that are not fun.